# strange result in dart list how to solve this

Tags: dart

i have the following

```
List list1 = [];
List list2 = [];

list2 = list1 ;

list1.add(1);

print(list1); // outputs [1] 
print(list2); // outputs [1] WHY?
```

i only change `list1` .. why `list2` is always be the same ..

sometimes in my app i need to make a list == another .. and this is great .. but once i make it they always be equals to each other even if i make a change to one of them

Comment: Just run it like:
```list2 = List.from(list1);```

Comment: More explanation of pointers and how it works you can find at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66559509/10180836).

Comment: Ooh .. i have studying dart since 4 years . still i discover more !! .. this is the first time iu know about pointers  ... thanks Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign list copy with `List.of` constructor method:

```dart
list2 = List.of(list1);
```

More explanation of pointers and how it works you can find at [my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66559509/10180836)

Comment: `List.from` loses type information. [You should prefer `List.of` or `.toList`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-listfrom-unless-you-intend-to-change-the-type-of-the-result).

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for saving me .. can you explain more of what do you mean of losses type information ?

Comment: @MohammedHamdan See [In Dart, what's the difference between List.from and .of, and between Map.from and .of?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50320220)